# word permutation with repetition where words are used multiple times

Tags: c#, permutation

I am trying to generate a list of combinations from an array of words.

I have been using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G to generate Combinations

```
var words = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\words.txt");
var allCombinations = new List<string>();

var combis = new Combinations<string>(words, 3, GenerateOption.WithRepetition);
allCombinations.AddRange(combis.Select(c => c.Aggregate((j, k) => j + "-" + k)));
```

given 3 words "Word1", "Word2" and "Word3" I get a list of combinations like

```
"Word1-Word1-Word1"
"Word1-Word1-Word2"
"Word1-Word1-Word3"
```

etc.

But I am missing combinations where a word is used multiple times

```
"Word1-Word2-Word1"
"Word1-Word3-Word1"
"Word2-Word1-Word2"
```

How do I get combinations of words that uses words multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is basically like counting in base 3:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 2
0 2 0
// and so on..
```

If the library you're using doesn't implement the logic you require, you can implement it yourself. Here is the idea:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Permutate(string[] words)
{
    // 0 0 0
    int[] indices = new int[words.Length];

    // yield 0 0 0
    yield return string.Join("-", indicies.Select(x => words[x]));

    // moves to 0 0 1 and so on, returns false after 3 3 3
    while (CountStep(indicies))
    {
        // yield next permutation
        yield return string.Join("-", indicies.Select(x => words[x]));
    }
}
```

Implementing CountStep is not hard either:

```
public static bool CountStep(int[] arr)
{
    // assumes we count in base N for an N sized array
    var maxDigit = arr.Length - 1;

    for (var i = arr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (arr[i] < maxDigit)
        {
            arr[i]++;

            for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                arr[j] = 0;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```